# Embed data in a page from a different website

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I have a problem that I know many people must know the answer to, but I am afraid I am still a bit of a beginner with these things.

I have been asked to make data on of my pages on one of our sites, available to another one of our sites (different servers)
The data is pulled from a MySQL server using php.

I have been told of iFrame but I think what I am looking for is

```
<?php
$othersite = file_get_contents('http://www.othersite.com');
echo $othersite;
?>
```

I know that this is possible because there is a file on our site that is a simple table populated by php from a database table (connection to database is an include file with the credentials) and it has been shared with a different site that has somehow embeded it into their page and it displays data live from our table.

Unfortunaley the person who originally set this up is not available.

Is the `file_get_contents` the answer I am looking for?

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers Al.

Comment: You can use include() and require() for that. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp. file_get_contents() reads file and load into a string.

Comment: include() and require() don't seem to work when trying to include a file from a different website, and your link to w3schools makes no mention of including from a different website, only local.

Comment: You should enable allow_url_include for that (in php.ini). Which is disabled by default. http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Allow_url_include.

Comment: That must not be the way the original example is done as it is working still, and a test of include() doesn't work. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on how you want to integrate, but I would actually recomment using an HTML `<iframe>` for this purpose. Clean integration, clean security separation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, SiteA has the database and a table with the data pulled by php. I want to have that table, with that data, on siteB. I know it is do-able as it is in place and working on a different website, but I can't tell how it was done. I'm pretty sure it wasn't with an iFrame though. If I need to use an iFrame then I wil, but I had a feeling this would be an obvious one.

Comment: I have tried an iFrame and it seems to work rather well. I know that the developer who did it originally with the other working example, didn't use an iFrame and was against them. Is there anything I should be worried about using an iFrame? Any thing to be careful of? It seems the perfect solution otherwise.